# Galois Field ($2^{16}$) for encryption in place of $GF(2^8)$ in AES

Tags: encryption, aes, algorithm-design

AES algorithm is using $GF(2^8)$ Galois Field. What if we use $GF(2^{16})$ in place of $GF(2^8)$? Will this improve the algorithm or not?

Comment: You have to provide the whole algorithm. Out of this context, your question makes no sens.

Comment: Looking at the evaluation criteria of the AES competition, one sees that the algorithm should be efficiently implementable on different platforms including 8-bit platforms (for smart cards). Using a field of size $2^{16}$ and therefore tables of size 128kB would have killed the Rijndael as AES-candidate.

Comment: I have an algorithm in the design phase (SP type 256-bit block cipher) that uses a $GF(2^{16})$ s-box with a 16x16 matrix multiplication, it is slow, but has excellent diffusion and nonlinearity

Answer (score 1):

The result would not be *AES*, but <s>*Rijndael*</s>  *a generalization of Rijndael*. The Rijndael originally was proposed with 1 block size (128 bits) and 5 key sizes (from 128 to 256 is jumps of 32 bits). In the standardization to become AES, only 3 were selected (jumps of 64 bits).

What makes block size to be 128? Each of the internal operations does its contribution. The wordsize is 8 bits (That's why the Galois Field has this size), and there are 4 columns and 4 rows. That makes $4*4*8 = 128$. The key sizes difference comes from the number of columns. Each extra column, as it has 4 rows, adds 32 bits. The AES adds 2 columns for each increment.

It is possible to play with this parameters, but you'll have to study individually to each of the Rijndael's operations what this change mean. Imho, the *Pseudo Random generator* (PRG) of the key expansion, I think will still be, at least, as valid as it is. The *subBytes* operation would experiment a size explosion that may affect the performance. Perhaps *shiftRows* and *mixColumns* would be the less affected. And don't forget how many *rounds* would be a good number.

As a summary, would this improve the algorithm? It can, if it comes with the appropriate adjustment of the other parameters. But then, if you implement it, you'll be away of the standard.